# Resetting Basketball score in Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I have been playing this addicted basketball game on Facebook messenger with my friends, but now we want to reset the score to 0 so that we can start all over again. We don't want to lose our chat history, so deleting the chat is not an option.

Is there any other way to do it?

Please help me with that, I have search all over the internet but there is no answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the old group chat. Simply start a new group chat anytime you want to start a new game and send a link to the new chat in the old group chat.

Comment: This is the correct answer. There is no reset feature.

Comment: what if its not a group chat ? I tried deleting old chat and starting a new one, score still not reset

Answer (score -2):

[image] hope this helps it’s how I deleted and restarted my games